# Qt - the performance difference between QOpnGLWidget and normal QWidget

Tags: qt, opengl

Widgets like QLabel can be used to display an image by calling the function `setPixmap(...)`. Or this can be done by using `QPainter::drawPixmap(...)` in `paintEvent(...)`. As I know, QOpenGLWidget/openGL is asking the GPU to work for it.

Therefore, I reckon the performance of QOpenGLWidget will be better. So what about the normal QWidgets? Are they asking the GPU to work when displaying images or drawing things?

Widgets look similar, but QOpenGLWidget has a special method `paintGL(...)`. I don't often see `paintEvent(...)` used for QOpenGLWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Normal QWidgets are generally rendered by the CPU, though they MAY use GPU for blitting backing stores, but that is usually only triggered by the presence of a QOpenGLWidget in the same window. Some platforms might default to OpenGL rendering, but think only the iOS platform did that, and I am not sure it still does.

As for performance, it depends. OpenGL has a higher overhead, but generally for images the greatly improved pixel processing speed outweighs any overhead. CPU rendering has benefit in incremental rendering, where it can more easily repaint small parts of the window, where OpenGL *generally* just repaints the entire window on each frame.